# ¿Eliminar datos de dos tablas Mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quisiera eliminar datos de dos tablas distintas en Mysql con PHP, tengo la siguientes tablas;

Tabla Revista

```
id_revista|no_revista|colaboradores|imagen  |fecha_publicacion|archivo|clave
1         |No. 1     | Ana Luna    |img.jpg |2017-12-06       |1.pdf  |cb12
```

Tabla Articulo

```
id_articulo|articulo   |autor        |clave
1          |Vivir bien |Juan Sanches |cb12
```

la clave de ambas tablas es la misma, la cual se guarda sin problema, para insertar utilizo la siguiente consulta;

```
public function registro($no_revista, $colaboradores, $fecha_publicacion, $imagen, $archivo, $articulo, $autor){
$sql = "INSERT INTO revista (no_revista, colaboradores, fecha_publicacion, imagen, archivo) VALUES ('$no_revista', '$colaboradores', '$fecha_publicacion', '$imagen', '$archivo')";
$consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql);
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO articulos (articulo, autor) 
VALUES ('$articulo', '$autor')";
$consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql1);
```

como hago para que si la elimino de la tabla revista se eliminen de la tabla articulos todas las que tienen la misma clave?

Tengo dos botones eliminar y actualizar quisiera que al oprimir eliminar este elimine la inserción de la tabla revista y de la tabla articulo los datos insertados que tienen la misma clave

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al botón como puedo agregar esa función?

Answer (score 2):

**ADVERTENCIA**

Tu codigo tiene severos bugs the [inyeccion SQL](http://bobby-tables.com/) porque la informacion del usuario es insertada directamente en el query. Cada que se pueda, debes usar prepared statements (si no sabes que es lo que son, echale un vistazo a [este](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) articulo de la W3). Son muy sencillos de hacer utilizando una de las APIs disponibles para PHP ([`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) o [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)), donde se inserta la informacion del usuario utilizando placeholders (valores parametrizados como `?` o `:name`), los cuales despues se remplazan con `bind_param` or `execute`, depede cual estes usando. NUNCA debes introducir la informacion en un query directamente de `$_POST` o `$_GET`.

Implementando el procedimiento propuesto puedes modificar el codigo para que funcione de la siguiente manera:

```
public function removerEntrada($clave) {
    $tables = array(
      array(
        "table" => "revista",
        "col" => "clave",
        "clave" => $clave
      ),
      array(
        "table" => "articulos",
        "col" => "clave",
        "clave" => $clave
      )
    );

    foreach ($tables as $entry) {
        $stmt = $this->conecta()->prepare("DELETE FROM {$entry['table']} where {$entry['col']} = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $entry["clave"]);

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            // Maneja el error de ejecucion
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora, como vas a implementar el uso de la libreria `mysqli` te recomiendo leer [esta](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) guia sobre como configurar la conexion, pero en resumen es tecnicamente crear un object `mysql`:

```
// Asumo que la propiedad llamada por el metodo conecta() es conexion
$this->conexion = new mysql("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la estructura que tienes en tu código y demás, yo haría algo así:

(No se si sea lo mas correcto, me baso en la forma en la que insertas los datos)

```
public function eliminar($clave){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM revista WHERE clave = '$clave'";
    $consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql);
    $sql1 = "DELETE FROM articulos WHERE clave = '$clave'";
    $consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql1);
}
```

Comment: Tengo en una interfaz los dos botones de eliminar y actualizar, solo mando llamar la función en el botón? agregue imagen en la pregunta, la forma en que hago la inserción no es la mas adecuada?

Comment: @R.Vivi entonces lo que quieres usar es ajax ?

Comment: @R.Vivi El procedimiento utilizado no es adecuado puesto que presenta problemas de seguridad muy graves. No debes de armar codigo no funcional para implementarlo en ambientes de produccion. Porfavor echale un vistazo a mi respuesta y asegurate de revisar los recursos que enlace para que corrijas la logica adecuadamente.

Comment: @AntonioHernández tienes toda la razón en que no es una forma segura, pero funcional si es...en mi respuesta soy enfático al afirmar "No se si sea lo mas correcto, me baso en la forma en la que insertas los datos" si quieres mostrarle una forma mas eficiente y segura de hacer peticiones a la DB podrías agregar un ejemplo básico, no solo texto...ahora por lo que parece ella requiere usar ajax...saludos !

Comment: Digo que no es funcional tomando en cuenta que no es aplicable para ningun caso en la vida real. Si tu tomas ese codigo y lo presentas como una solucion viable claramente vas a quedar en un problema ante tus superiores (y peor seria si aceptan dicho codigo). Tienes razon con agregar un ejemplo, pero considero que alguien aprende mucho mas revisando recursos directamente que con una solucion prefabricada por alguien mas, en cualquier caso ya agregue la muestra. Y pues si el problema ya es diferente se debe de modificar la descripcion de la pregunta @R.Vivi

Comment: @AntonioHernández exacto, esperos que responda y/o edite la pregunta